# How to fix a race condition in an async architecture?

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture, messaging, system-design

I have an async architecture that is not behaving as expected. Consider the following components:

- Payment Service
- External Payment Service*
- Confirmed Payments Topic*
- Confirmed Payments Consumer
- Payments database

I own the payment service, confirmed payments consumer and payments database. The other two components are owned by a separate team.

Payments should go through this flow, as depicted in the sequence diagram below: first, the payment service calls the external payment service to make a payment. After the external service returns, my service will update the payment on the database. Once the payment is confirmed, the external payment service is supposed to post a message in the "Confirmed payments topic", which will be consumed by my "Confirmed payments consumer". Knowing that the payment was confirmed, it updates the payment on the database.

[image]

Note that there's two components updating the payment on the database: Payment service and Confirmed Payment Consumer. So there's a catch. A race condition, more specifically. If the external payment service writes the message to the topic too quickly, or if it takes too long to send a response, maybe the updates will happen out of order (green and red arrows). Then, the payment will end up with the wrong status.

How could I fix this? I need to call external payment service to make a payment, and should write the payment to the database with a "PENDING" status while it does not confirm the payment. However, I can only know the payment is confirmed once I get a message on the confirmed payments topic.

I'm using kafka as a message broker and Quarkus/Java to implement the APIs and consumers.

Answer (score 0):

So usually you will want to just use appropriate transaction levels to corresponding updates and handle the concurrency issues if any arises (based on what concurrency guaranties your storage allows).

In general I would argue that this is a relatively an easy one. Since for the `PENDING` there is  only one valid previous status you can use [the testing for optimistic concurrency violation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/optimistic-concurrency#testing-for-optimistic-concurrency-violations) approach, i.e. (for most relational databases) you can just use query looking something like the following:

```sql
update Payment 
  set Status = 'PENDING'
where Id = ... and Status = some_previous_status
```

You can take this a step further and introduce some version column which will be incremented/update on every change. For example some ORM frameworks have such functionality as build in one ([EF Core for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations#optimistic-concurrency)).